# How to resize the size of list items in Jquery Mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to reduce the size of list items in Jquery Mobile with no success, I have tried a lot of codes I have found on SO. below is the code I last tried;

```
#class_list {
    height:100%;
}
#class_list li {
    height: 20%;
}
```

The list item is dynamically generated.

Comment: pretty sure you need to create a grid that flanks the list, and then adjust grid size. see this part of API:    http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: @tasos actually answered it but deleted his answer

Comment: ill put it back. i assume one of those methods worked, if not do a demo on fiddle and i sorted it out. dynamic or non dynamic list items are the same when it comes to css

Comment: ok cool, when you posted the comment i was in middle of updating the answer for some other possible ways to get a custom height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to set a custom height for the list items, but i think percentage wont work. You could use jquery to get the screen size and divide it by the number of items and then update the css dynamically in pixels.

**Demo** modifying the JQM's given CSS name for static list items

http://jsfiddle.net/b53bg0j5/

**CSS**

```
.ui-listview>.ui-li-static {
height: 60px;
}
```

=================================================

**Demo** own class for list items with (!important) to enable it over JQM's original rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/52aey3o6/

**CSS**

```
.b {
height: 25px !important;
}
```

==================================================

direct css rule for li element

```
li {
height: 66px;
}
```

==================================================

custom list by adding a class for the (ul) element

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="FF">

.FF>li {
height: 46px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. While this work for a static list, it does not work for my dynamically generated list. I should point out that the generated list has images, and two `<p></p>` tags